# Route wire under the capacitor

Tags: capacitor

There are caps in the red rectangular area. However, there is ground path between capacitor place holder. Those caps are used to filter high frq signal in the DC line. It would not degrade the performance of caps, right?

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, this is completely fine, but I can't tell how power and ground are routed on the other layers. E.g. why are there no vias on the outer electrodes? They look like stubs, which are pretty poor at filtering anything HF because the signal doesnt have to pass through these areas.

Comment: @tobalt Thank you for the comment. Because of a manufacturing issue, it cannot add vias at the electrodes..

Comment: They don't have to be *in* the pads. What I mean is: Where do these outer electrodes lead? And why should HF noise travel through these capacitors before offending downstream devices? Essentially you will have a substantial *inductance* in series with your capacitors.